# TypeError: undefined is not a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys am new to javascript and when i tried some piece of code its showing type error ..The code is

```
var something = function(element){
    this.name = "oops";
    this.some = function(element) { console.log(this.name); }; 
    element.addEventListner('click', this.some, false); 
}
```

When i called the above function like `var b = something("baba");` its showing error `TypeError: undefined is not a function`..I dunno why it happens like this..

Hope you can help me ..Thanks

Comment: addEventListener is spelled wrong.

Comment: will it work if i add like element.addEventListner('click', this.some.bind(this) false); ..here the this points to the object of the function b right ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First **addEventListner**  should be **addEventListener**

Next You are binding a click event to the element in question.

Where as you seem to be passing in a string and then binding the event to it. 
(make sure the argument you pass in is a valid object to which events can be bound to).

The context of `this` inside the function will be the window object. So you would need to bind the context to the event.

```
var something = function(element){
    this.name = "oops";
    this.some = function(element) { console.log(this.name); }; 
    element.addEventListener('click', this.some.bind(this), false); 
}

var elem = document.getElementById('elem'); 

var b = something(elem);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5Ljg/)**

Comment: will it work if i add like element.addEventListner('click', this.some.bind(this) false); ..here the this points to the object of the function b right ??

Comment: +1 for adding complete code plus jsfiddle... you totally beat me :)

Comment: this corresponds to the object that we have called right ??..var baby = something() ..so b will act as this right ??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, fix the typo mentioned by @Sushanth

Make sure you bind the function to the object you want the `some` function to have as `this`.

Here's what the coude should look like:

```
var something = function(element){
    this.name = "oops";
    this.some = function(element) { console.log(this.name); }; 
    element.addEventListener('click', this.some.bind(this), false); 
}
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/y2BPm/1/

**Edit**: The function you added to `this.some` could be anything and will have no idea what you meant by using `this`, unless you actually tell it "bind it" to an object, in which case `this` inside the function will be whatever you binded it to. In this case, the `something` function

Comment: this corresponds to the object that we have called right ??..var baby = something() ..so b will act as this right ??

Answer (score 0):

Continuing to 
First **addEventListner** should be **addEventListener**

Consider only below thing:

var b = something("baba");

here **"baba"** is a string. Your function is expecting an element.

eg.

```
   var something = function (element) {
            this.name = "oops";
            this.some = function (element) { console.log(this.name); };
            element.addEventListener('click', this.some, false);
        }   




<input type="button" value="click here" onclick="something(this);" name="TestName" />
```

Above code should work....

Comment: this corresponds to the object that we have called right ??..var baby = something() ..so b will act as this right ??